# How to prevent Google Cloud Pub/Sub push subscriptions to send old tokens

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jwt, google-cloud-pubsub

We're using a Google Cloud Pub/Sub push subscriptions with authentication.
Sometimes the HTTPS call includes old tokens.
They are about 1 hour old, which may indicate a time zone issue or so, but after the endpoint returns 401 (not authorized), the call is retried with another token, about half an hour old.

In principal, the system works, because of the retry, but I cannot imagine that Google would send a request with an old token.

Does anybody have an idea on how to fix this?

Example:
Log from receiving endpoint (GMT+1):

```
2020-01-06 01:57:27.5975|ERROR|Google.Apis.Auth.InvalidJwtException: JWT has expired.
```

JWT contains payload:

```
{
  "exp": 1578272235,
  "iat": 1578268635
}
```

```
"iat": 1578268635
GMT: Sunday 5. January 2020 23:57:15
Your time zone: mandag d. 6. januar 2020 kl. 00:57:15 GMT+01:00

"exp": 1578272235
GMT: Monday 6. January 2020 00:57:15
Your time zone: mandag d. 6. januar 2020 kl. 01:57:15 GMT+01:00
```

Comment: Tokens are valid for 3600 seconds. I do not know at what point Google refreshes the tokens. I recommend posting an Issue Tracker so that Google can investigate: https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers

Comment: How are you determining that the token is one hour old? Is the time on your system accurate? More details on your system's logic will be necessary. Tokens do not have a timezone, they are GMT.

Comment: See added example: Token was either expired or close to expiration time when it was sent from PubSub.

Comment: Your update does not answer my questions. Also, what is the time as reported by an external time authority? It is possible that there is a GCP bug (open an Issue Tracker item) but my suspicion is that you have a time issue with your system.

Comment: The endpoint log is determining the token is expired. This time correlates with the StackDriver log time of the 401 error. Of course, there easily can be a 12 second delay as in the example consisting of latency and a time error, but that still raises the question why GCP would include a token that is (or almost is) expired.

Comment: carens, are you still seeing an issue with expired tokens?

Comment: I can only see one or two 401 errors in the last month, so it seems it got a lot better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON Web Token included with a push request can be up to an hour old. There may be an issue in Cloud Pub/Sub that results in tokens expiring before they reach a push endpoint, and it is under investigation.

For more information, please see the documentation on using JSON Web Tokens here: https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push#using_json_web_tokens_jwts

Comment: does subscriber authenticate message by JWT ?